# How to get the maximum value from within a column in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a DataFrame (df_testing) with the following sample data:

[image: DataFrame(Before)]

I need to get the max value from the Amount column. So the output DataFrame (dfnew) looks like this:

[image: DataFrame(After)]

I'm a newbie in pyspark, so I looped through the dataframe using the following code:

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    rec_count = df_testing.count()
    MaxValuesArray = [] #empty array
    TransactionArray = [] #empty array

    for i in range(0, rec_count):
        vMaxValue = max(df_testing.cache().collect()[i]["Amount"].split(","))
        vTransactionId = df_testing.cache().collect()[i]["Id"]
        TransactionArray.append(vTransactionId)
        MaxValuesArray.append(vMaxValue)

    X = np.array([TransactionArray,MaxValuesArray])
    Y = {'Id':X[0], 'MaxValue':X[1]}

    df = pd.DataFrame(Y) #convert array to panda dataframe
    SparkDF = spark.createDataFrame(df) #convert to spark dataframe
    a=df_testing.alias("a")
    b=SparkDF.alias("b")
    dfnew = a.join(b,a.Id ==  b.Id,"inner").select('a.*','b.MaxValue') #join dataframes
    dfnew.show(truncate=False)
```

While the code above works, it's highly inefficient. The sample has 3 records, but on a daily basis I need to work with approximately 25000 records. It takes over 2 hours to loop through (attaching to small spark spool) 25000 records.

My understanding is Pyspark DataFrame is very powerful, but I just don't have the expertise to get the max value as part of a dataset, rather than looping through the DataFrame.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Setup

```
df.show()

+-----------+
|     Amount|
+-----------+
|100,200,300|
|200,400,100|
|  1000,2500|
|  100.1,1,2|
|        100|
+-----------+
```

##### Solution

Split the strings in amount column around `,` then cast the array of string to array of floats and use the `array_max` function to find the maximum value

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn('max', F.array_max(F.split('Amount', ',').cast('array<float>')))
```

##### Result

```
df.show()
+-----------+------+
|     Amount|   max|
+-----------+------+
|100,200,300| 300.0|
|200,400,100| 400.0|
|  1000,2500|2500.0|
|  100.1,1,2| 100.1|
|        100| 100.0|
+-----------+------+
```